Rich Text Area Field in LWC don't respond with dynamic retrieved content
i'm new with salesforce lwc, i did implement Rich Text Area Field in my code
and this the code from
it works fine when i tape text and apply changes but when i charge a dynamic content when i select somthing in combobox it doesn't work
see in here demo i uploaded a gif
Demo gif link
this is my actual code html
<template if:true={withEmail}>
  <lightning-card
    variant="Narrow"
    title="Rich Text Area Field in LWC"
    icon-name="standard:account"
  >
    <div class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
      <lightning-input-rich-text
        value={emailTextAreaValue}
        label={fieldLabel}
        label-visible
        required={requirdded}
        formats={allowedFormats}
        class="visibleLines"
        onchange={handletextAreaChange}
        share-with-entity-id={recordId}
        message-when-bad-input={errorMessage}
      >
      </lightning-input-rich-text>
    </div>
</template>

js
 @track emailTextAreaValue = "";
  fieldLabel;
  requirdded;
  fieldLength = 32000;
  visibleLines = 3;
  @api recordId;

  errorMessage;
  allowedFormats = [
    "font",
    "size",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "underline",
    "strike",
    "list",
    "indent",
    "align",
    "link",
    "image",
    "clean",
    "table",
    "header",
    "color",
    "background",
    "code",
    "code-block",
    "script",
    "blockquote",
    "direction"
  ];

  handletextAreaChange(event) {
    this.emailTextAreaValue = event.target.value;
  }

  @track emailTextAreaValue = ""; 

and this is how i charge value for emailTextAreaValue and it fill the Rich Text Area Field when i select the combobox

  handleTemplateChange(event) {
    this.selectedTemplateId = event.detail.value;
    getAll({ templateId: event.detail.value })
      .then((data) => {
       some code
        this.emailTextAreaValue = data.renderedEmailTemplateBody;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
             some code
      });
  }


can pls someone help me

Doesn’t your gif show that it is working? It’s really hard to tell what part isn’t working. Please edit your question to clearly call out the expected behaviour and how you’ve determined it isn’t working

Please watch the gif till the end i showed you how its works with words i tape but it foes not work with value when i select something from the combobox and this is the problem

I did watch the gif, and as you see towards the end of the gif, when you change the text justification the styles are updated.  This is why I'm asking how did you determine it isn't working?  Perhaps it is updating but you can't see if because the text area isn't tall enough to see any of your changes.

You are doing a lot of activity in the gif and I cannot determine the specific action that you are referrring to.  Please [edit] your post to describe the specific action you are doing and the specific results you expect, and where in  the rich text field we should be looking.
